# Form processing $_POST to variables automatically

Tags: php

I have about 40 items in my `FORM` and i'm trying to give all the `Name=` properties a variable for process without having to write each out manually. am I missing something here, cause the code below is not working. (name="comp1", name="comp2"... $comp1, $comp2)

```
$en = array_merge($em, $_POST);
$valid = true; 
foreach($_POST as $value) { 
    if(!isset($value)) { 
        $valid = false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: use `empty()` to check for empty values, not isset

Comment: `$value` will always be set in your code.

Comment: @acctman: i have expanded my answer, take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 4):

If something is not in `$_POST`, the foreach will not loop through it. `Isset()` will always return true, because the foreach loops through all values in `$_POST`.

Comment: WHY do people assume ISSET() relates to the value of the variable not if it exists? (apart form NULL or byte \0)

Answer (score 3):

```
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$val) { 
    //$$k = $val;
       if(!isset($$k)){
         echo "==NO==";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the POST will always be set, unless you disable the field with something like this:

`<input disabled="disabled"/>`

If the filds doesn't have this attribute, the only way to check if the field was filled is a comparse with an empty string, with `$value == ''` this way:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if($value == '') { 
        $valid[$key] = false;
   }else{
        $valid[$key] = true;
   }
}
```

You will have now an array ($valid) that will look like:

```
var_dump($valid['field1']); //prints true, the field was filled
var_dump($valid['field2']); //prints false, the field was NOT filled
```

Comment: and its not the only way. using empty() as @ellabeauty said will work too.